# Cakephp elements not working

Tags: cakephp

Here I have a model called gssnews.I want to view this gssnews in another model called dashboard.So,I have made a file called news.ctp in elements file.Here is the code

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr class="active">

            <th>News Title</th>
            <th>News Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo h($gssNews['GssNews']['news_title']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo h($gssNews['GssNews']['news_description']); ?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

The output image like this 
[image]

Here problem gssnews information not viewing.
Here I am trying two things

1. See the news in dashboard
2. only 2 news will show from
       table.

So,how can I pass this information and apply find methods with limit 2 in elements.

Here is my gssnews controller **`view method`**

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$this->GssNews->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid gss news'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array('GssNews.' . $this->GssNews->primaryKey => $id));
    $this->set('gssNews', $this->GssNews->find('first', $options));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

LIMIT of 2 : //update in your controller

```
 $options = array(
              'conditions' => array('GssNews.' . $this->GssNews->primaryKey => $id),
              'limit' => 2 //limit to 2
            );
 $this->set('gssNews', $this->GssNews->find('all', $options)); //changed your previous "first" to "all"
```

news.ctp:

```
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <tr class="active">
        <th>News Title</th>
        <th>News Description</th>
      </tr>
       <?php foreach($gssNews as $gssNews): ?>
          <tr>
             <td><?php echo h($gssNews['GssNews']['news_title']); ?></td>
             <td><?php echo h($gssNews['GssNews']['news_description']); ?></td>
           </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
  </table>
```

In the view of your dashboard:

```
 <?php echo $this->element("news");?>
```

Comment: Here the 1st issue is pass data in elements.Here nothing is showing after add <td><?php echo h($gssNews['GssNews']['news_title']); ?></td>
             <td><?php echo h($gssNews['GssNews']['news_description']); ?></td>  this two line in elements/news.ctp

Comment: I have update my answer. You should add this to the vioew of your dashboard <?php echo $this->element("news");?>

Comment: I have already added this.Here in your ans which controller have to update ?

Comment: Your gssnews controller: in your view method